# Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0)

Tags: react-native

i am running sample application...... I am using [this](https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge) module..... But i am getting error like this...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-google-analytics-bridge'.
   > Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/25.2.0/support-v4-25.2.0.aar
```

> My module version is :"react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^5.2.2"

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: may be try excluding this library like: `compile(project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')){ exclude(group: 'com.android.support') }`

Answer (score 2):

[image]In such cases of failure, sometimes the module linking doesn't go well.Please try to link the module manually as described in the link :https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/wiki/Manual-installation
and/or try replace "support-v4:25.2.0" with compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'.
Location: Android/App/build.gradle

Comment: Hi @Himanshu, I followed this link [https://github.com/idehub/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/wiki/Manual-installation] but I am getting same error.....
`Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0).`

Comment: @Harika Try using the other option by changing version for your android support as described.

Comment: In my Android/App/build.gradle file....there is no `com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1` then how i will change my version........

Comment: Refer screenshot.you should have something like compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0' replace that with compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'

Comment: @Himanush, I have my Android/App/build.gradle file like this:
`dependencies {
     compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}`

Comment: Add>>  compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1' 
with your dependencies.It's are missing and hence the error.

Comment: I added this line `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'` but this is also not working for me......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173118/discussion-between-harika-and-himanshu-g).

Comment: did you found any soultion of this i am facing same problen for support-v4.arr not found